# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80080005

Tags: .net, com, interop

What is the troubleshooting process for the "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80080005" errors in .Net? To clarify: I am getting this at runtime, on my XP machine, with client being .net code running under admin account. {XXXX} refers to one of our in-house COM components.

From what I understand, 0x80080005 refers to "permission denied", but where do I go to check/change the permissions? Or am I completely wrong here, and the error is coming from the component itself, and not out of Windows COM subsystem?

Comment: Your question may be too vague to receive a meaningful answer. Are you receiving this error at compile-time? Run-time? What COM component is causing the error? If error is at run-time, are you running as a non-admin user on XP or Vista?

Comment: Really need more info to answer. Is your app a desktop app?  Is it running as a std user or admin?  Is the COM object local or remote?

Comment: I've ran into something similar.  I can say-at least from my own experience-that it can occur from an app that is ran locally, ran under the context of a service account while that svc acct is your own user name while you have Admin privileges on the machine, and the COM object was local to the machine.  The error would occur when trying to initiate code that accesses the COM object.  I agree which COM object still is left out - in my example, it was the Word object.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems to be a rather generic error relating to starting up the COM server. Possible issues include [timeouts](http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/archive/2005/06/24/432519.aspx), [logon failures](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/ComSecurityFaqEx2.html) (check the Q about `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`), or [security permissions](http://www.devguy.com/fp/Tips/COM/), or (evidently) a [VS2008 ATL bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/jigarme/archive/2008/05/08/cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-for-visual-studio-2008-based-atl-service.aspx). Hitting an error in CreateInstance would do the trick as well, I think.

I'd start by checking Event Log for anything interesting.

Comment: I just dug up server's source code. It is C++/ATL. Shudder. It appears to be easier to work around this stuff then to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hi. Your post is very interesting. However, the links in it seem to have a syntax problem, and the secfac.htm seems to have moved to http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/ComSecurityFaqEx2.html

Comment: Should avoid link only answers and supply some of the things under these to check, instead.  The "logon failures" and "security permissions" links are already dead links.  The ATL bug should no longer apply if the developer is using VS 2008 SP1 or above.

Answer (score 1):

0x80080005 is "Server Execution Failed", according to ERRLOOK.EXE. WinError.h lists this as `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`. Not "Access Denied".

Comment: D'oh. Thanks! Does this mean that the server failed, or that COM failed to instantiate the server?

Comment: This should've been made as a comment, not an answer.  This doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can look at is the DCOM security configuration.  It is controlled by the dcomcnfg utility.  There are [helpful tutorial videos](http://www.opcactivex.com/Support/Tutorials/DCOM_Tutorial_-_Configuring_th/DCOM_Videos/dcom_videos.html) on the web to explain how to use it.  There is also a [thread on the ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1093228.aspx) forum that discusses how to use dcomcnfg.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  The tutorial is now a dead link.  The thread is relevant - what he did was to add permission to the DCOM Config > Microsoft Word 93-2000 remote launch activation for the Network Service account.  You should've just added that here.  A SO link (which will be active so long as this page is) has the instructions on how to do that, though they recommend using the Interactive User, or none, if that doesn't work, so 3 options:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the