# PHP Component Object Model "Access is denied"

Tags: php, iis, com

My development environment is PHP 5.3, IIS 7.5, and Window7 Home. I am developing a prototype application, which requires the PHP function imagewindowgrab(). This function requires calling the Windows Component Object Model (COM).

My single line of code was this:

```
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application") or die("Unable to instantiate IE");
```

It produced the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 
'Failed to create COM object `InternetExplorer.Application': Access is denied. ' 
in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php(8): com->com('InternetExplore...') #1 {main} thrown 
in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php on line 8
```

After searching for hours, trolling through .NET forums, and finding good resources:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1680634.aspx/1
- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

What finally worked for me was following the instructions outlined in the answer to this SO question:
[Accessing Office Word object model through asp.net results in "failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the)

AND following up those instructions with the following:

1. On the command line enter `DCOMCNFG`
2. Click right on Console *Root > Component Service > Computers > My Computer* and select *Properties*
3. On the tab *COM Security > Access Permissions* click on *Edit Default* and add the user (e.g. *IIS_IUSRS*) or service
4. Check allow local access

This appears to have taken care of my Access Permission problems with the COM framework from PHP.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should put your solution as an answer and then accept it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

This question appears unanswered but answer have self explained in question .
I am just putting here :-

**Tried Code :-**

```
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application") or die("Unable to instantiate IE");
```

**Error Generated :-**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 
'Failed to create COM object `InternetExplorer.Application': Access is denied. ' 
in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php(8): com->com('InternetExplore...') #1 {main} thrown 
in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\trial.php on line 8
```

**Steps and resources that helped to solved :-**

Good Resources:-

http://forums.asp.net/t/1680634.aspx/1

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Resources that actually help to solve :-

[Accessing Office Word object model through asp.net results in "failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the)

**Steps :-**

1. Open a command prompt window and type `DCOMCNFG` to open the Component Services interface.
2. Expand *Console Root* > *Component Service* > *Computers* and right-click on   *My Computer*, And Select *Properties*
3. In the Tab *COM Security* > *Access Permissions*   Click on *Edit Default*
   Add the User (Ex. IIS_IUSRS) or service
4. Check *Allow* for *Local Access*

**Note : Take care of Access Permission problems with the COM framework from PHP.**

Comment: Thanks alot! DCOMCNFG and Com Security solved my problem :)
[Failed to create COM object `AppX.Document': Access is denied]