# cant create word com object in php

Tags: php, com

i have a web application and I'm trying to crete a com object for microsoft word

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
```

I've installed office 2010 on my server
and at first i got a permissions denied error, so I followed this link to add permissions: http://www.figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24

but now im getting this error:
 Failed to create COM object `word.application': Server execution failed
any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Always follow these steps

1. On the command line enter DCOMCNFG
2. Click right on Console Root >Component Service > Computers > My Computer and select Properties
3. On the tab COM Security > Access Permissions click on Edit Default and
   add the user (e.g. IIS_IUSRS) or service
4. Check allow local access

More info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561504/php-component-object-model-access-is-denied)

Comment: I followed thos steps already, and stopped getting the permissions denied error, but now im getting another error:Failed to create COM object `word.application': Server execution failed

Comment: What is the PHP version that you are using? It was a known bug in PHP before. Update to PHP5 if not latest..