# error reading oulook using MAPI in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, outlook, imap, mapi

I use VS2010, C#, ASP.NET to read outlook email. I've setup outlook express 6 with my gmail (IMAP), I get a strange exception at the first line, where my COM object is being created, here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem item = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;

try
{
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    ns.Logon("gmail_id", "gmail_pass", false, true);

    inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["MySubFolderName"]; //folder.Folders[1]; also works
    Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}, EntryId: {1}", subFolder.Name, subFolder.EntryID);
    Console.WriteLine("Num Items: {0}", subFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

    for (int i = 1; i <= subFolder.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem)subFolder.Items[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", i.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", item.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0} {1}", item.SentOn.ToLongDateString(), item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine("Categories: {0}", item.Categories);
        Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.Body);
        Console.WriteLine("HTMLBody: {0}", item.HTMLBody);
    }
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{

}
finally
{
    ns = null;
    app = null;
    inboxFolder = null;
}
```

it is my exception:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

this exception is create at the first line:

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

I've used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll` file as my interop reference, what is going wrong here? I can read my Gmail inbox in outlook express 6, but I have no luck in my ASP.NET web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring the [appropriate COM Activation permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833718/175679) for Office apps to run under ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks dear SilverNinja, I test it, but should this procedure be performed for each user? In fact I'm trying to write a WCF which can be accessed by my Silverlight application, it is going to be used for reading email, currently I read IMAP directly but outlook should be added also, where should I change these settings? on my server only?

Comment: This would only be done on the server for whichever account is running the Application Pool. For IIS 6 it would be IIS_IUSRS, but for IIS 7 it needs to be configured in the Application Pool settings.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not ever use any Office app (Outlook included) in a service (such as IIS). No exceptions, it is simply not supported.
Secondly, if you are using the Outlook Object Model (not in a service), you need to have Outlook (the real one) intalled. OE has nothing in common witt Outlook 2010/2007/2003/etc., except for the word "Outlook" in the name.

Comment: OK but how can I use outlook services in my server application? what are the other options?

Comment: You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), which exposes the RDO family of objects that can used in a service.