# Generating `docx` using Interop not working on terminating RDC

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, permissions, windows-server-2016

I have a ASP.Net framework web application that trying to create a `.docx`(or a `.pdf`) file from an invoice.

On my local machine, while in development environment, the code does its job fine.

But in production server I had a problem with, accessing IIS_Users to "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document".

I fix that problem by implementing the accepted answer of the following question.

[Accessing Office Word object model through asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the)

But now, when I close the remote desktop connection and trying to get file from website, I get error 500 from server and when remote again to server I can download file and my code works fine on the production server.

In other word when RDP is disconnect IIS can't access to "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document".

I think closing RDP causes to log off users and that's why IIS_Users cant access to "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document".

I have also googled this one and didn't find any way to fix it. Is there any way to let user stay signed in even after remote connection gets closed?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this right, but a process relying on a Service Account User being loggend on via RDP sounds fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Filburt please explain more.

Comment: Don't use Interop to create Word or Excel. It creates all kinds of problems like the ones you have. Use specialized libraries.

Comment: @MohammadRN I think Elendil's answer explains it pretty well.

Comment: @VDWWD what is your suggestion library for creating docx file from html ?

Comment: I havent used one myself, but maybe https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using COM to inteact with word document, you are actually interacting with desktop

after windows 2008, windows service does not support interact with desktop any more, and iis also runs inside svcHost, refer to :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc756339(v=ws.10)

that's why you can make it work while RDP to your server but failed to get the code run after disconnect from RDP

Edited, the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) Provided by Lex Li described in more detail.

Comment: That's incorrect. Your company has an official article on that https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Answer (score 2):

Use the DocX library, not interop:

NuGet:

```
Install-Package DocX -Version 1.3.0
```

GitHub: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx