# Couldn't find Microsoft Word Document in DCOM Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, ms-office, dcom

I am creating a simple asp.net web site that use office 2007/2010 automation .. when i published the website on the iis 7 on my local machine (window 7) have an exception

```
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
 {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 
 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 
 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

I have searched for this exception and i found that i have to set some permissions to office in DCOM Config.

I have opened the component services and opened DCOM Config, but i have not found Microsoft Word Document i have found only office word 97 - 2003.

can any one tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the

Comment: Note that https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1903690/Set-up-job-to-convert-word-document-to-pdf?PageIndex=2 links here.

Answer (score 24):

Found the answer here: [DCOM Failure of Office Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688853/dcom-failure-of-office-automation)

If you are running a 64-bit server with 32-bit Office, you may have trouble finding this DCOM setting. You will need to run "MMC -32" from the command prompt to launch 32-bit MMC and then add 'Component Services' from the 'File > Add / Remove Snap-ins' menu.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, *office word 97 - 2003* is a right name of DCOM document (resp. application) Word 2007 or 2010. Don't ask me why...

Where could be the trouble?

The user must have access to the desktop. If Word is called from ASP.NET, it probably doesn't have this access. So set an account specifically in *dcomcnfg.exe*. Don't use *The launching user* (it is an IIS identity, it doesn't have its own desktop) and don't use *The interactive user* (it only works if some user is logged in).

In my solution I have set:

- I have created a new user (in user group), called *WordUser*
- I have created in IIS a new application pool with *WordUser* permission; *Load User Profile* must be *true*
- DCOM: I have set to use *WordUser*, on *Security* tab I've added_ WordUser_ with *Launch and activation Permission* and *Access Permission*

Another way can be possible, but this way should work.

Comment: This solution worked for 64-bit Office 2016 on 64-bit Windows 10. Descriptions and steps are good enough.

Comment: Word 2019 still has Word 97 - 2003!