# Interop.Word Class Execution Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office-interop

I'm trying to debug a problem in a REST API I've built in .Net MVC.

In it, I'm trying to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library to do document manipulation.  My application works just fine on my local development box.  But, when I run it on the server (after a publish), it bombs with this message...

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

...on the following line:

`var application = new Application();`

This is where it first instantiates an instance of `Interop.Word.Application()`, which is the first part of my application that interacts with the `Interop.Word` library.  My research (and common sense) has led me to believe that there is some sort of a dependency that is present on my development machine, but is missing on the target server.  I'm essentially trying to figure out what that is.  I have found several message boards and articles and what-have-you on this site as well as others that have suggested an array of solutions from messing with DCOM settings ([Couldn't find Microsoft Word Document in DCOM Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300046/couldnt-find-microsoft-word-document-in-dcom-config)), to upgrading MS Office on the server.  None of that seems to work.  I've even seen someone suggest using a third-party component like GemBox.  But, having to use a third-party solution doesn't seem necessary seeing as how my application works just fine locally.  There has to be something missing on the server... some variation in the environment.  This cryptic error is not doing me any favors.

Does anyone have any suggestions... something I'm overlooking or that I can try?  Thanks!

Comment: [The office interop is not supported on asp.net](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office), if possible consider switching to the [Open XML SDK for Office by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) which is supported in server enviorments (however only supports the newer `.docx` file format) or some other 3rd party library if you need the older `.doc` file support.

Comment: I went with the GemBox solution.  Truth be told, a former developer had gone that route with another API he had developed for similar reasons.  Since the company already forked out for the license, I just used that.

Comment: Feel free to delete your question or post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Why don't you post the answer since you answered it, and I'll accept it?  I don't want to delete the question... someone else might come around searching for the same thing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Why can't you just leave it alone?  I obviously researched the issue and couldn't find the answer that this is a duplicate of, so... why do you even care?