# .net interface to COM server fails with 0x80080005

Tags: .net, com, interop

I have a native c++ COM server that exposes COM interfaces. I can successfully use a native c++ client application to get and use the exposed interfaces from the server.

When I use a .net client with a reference to the server, I get the error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

...even though the COM server starts and runs successfully (and only takes about 1 or 2 seconds to startup).

BUT I get the above error only when the server is registered as a local server. If I register the server as a windows service, the .net client can successfully get and use the interfaces just fine.

I'm doing all this as an admin on Windows 7 64-bit. The COM server is on the local machine.

I checked the thread below, but no answers were offered:
[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80080005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279112/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-th)

Spent a day and a half on this one so far...what could be the problem?

More information:
I've had this working with vs2005. I recently updated to vs2010 and am now running into this issue. I've tried building the .net client targeting frameworks 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0 with the same results.

Thanks

Comment: Is your COM server 32-bit? Are you running the 64-bit .NET CLR?

Comment: The COM server is 32-bit. I've built the .net client specifically for x86...is there anything else needed to target 32-bit CLR?

Comment: Could this be related to single vs multiple instances of the server? When registered as a service, everything works. Clients can connect to the server and do their work. When registered as a local server, a new instance of the server is started by each attempted client connection and then the 0x80080005 error happens; so after several tests I have several instances of the server running instead of just one.

Comment: smells like security problems to me.. are you running with elevated priviliges or are you just logged into windows as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error when using a .net app running on x64 to try to connect to a 32 bit COM app. I was able to fix it easily by switching my .net app to x86 (32 bit).

Answer (score -2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

For More information check this [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Office.

Comment: @BryanLegend He was thinking it was about this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the  But you're totally right.